# how to perform maths operation from a string using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a calculator by using jQuery. How to perform math operation from a string? I need to display calculator action to the output box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    var inputtt = $(this).val();
    var displayinput = $("#getinput").val();
    $("#getinput").val(displayinput + inputtt);
  })
  
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var displayinput = $("#getinput").val();
    var output = parseInt(displayinput);
    $("#output").val(displayinput);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calcform" method="post" style="background:lightgreen; padding:10px; ">
  <input type="text" id="output" value="" placeholder="OUTPUT" readonly><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="getinput" value="" placeholder="INPUT"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="-">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="+">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="*">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="/">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="c"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="1">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="2">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="3">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="4"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="5">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="6">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="7">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="8">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="9"><br><br>
  <button type="button" id="submit">=</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can either use `eval` to evaluate the string or you can parse through the string yourself, breaking it up and applying the operations step by step

Comment: Never use `eval`. I can recommend the way windows 10 calculator does it: you input first value, and by the time you click an operator (+, *, -, /), previous input is saved and parsed to integer, it saves what operator have you used, clears the input field and you are prompted for a second value. You can chain multiple operators by pushing it to an array for example.

Comment: ***Do not use `eval`***, especially for a user-entered text-box. The user could put any code they like in there, and you would run it, no questions asked.

Comment: Of course whenever you do use eval, sanitize your string beforehand, duh. When you do that, there is nothing wrong with using eval.

Answer (score 0):

use Math predefined object for that for example if I want to square

```
var y = Math.sqrt(16)
```

will find all the math options here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math